# How do I install gifsicle?

Tags: command-line, gif, animated-gif

I need a solution to create and edit gifs quickly. I found gifsicle to be a very good solution. The problem is that the program is very difficult to install. The github page for the software can be found at this [link](https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle)

Answer (score 3):

For linux... Assuming you have `build-essentials` installed, it's pretty quick to install.

```
curl -sL http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/gifsicle-1.91.tar.gz | tar -zx
cd gifsicle-1.91
./configure --disable-gifview
make install
```

Comment: I don't see why not. These are the official instructions for building on linux, as seen on the github page. https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle